# What does "much less both" in the following sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> Few historians have extensive training in critical theory and its
>   specialized languages, and the sheer volume of work in early American
>   history and literature challenges anyone who would master either
>   field, much less both.

Is it talking about the volume of work challenges people to become masters or reduces the challenges for people to become masters?
Also, does "sheer" mean "many" here?
I'm confused about the meaning of the whole sentence.

Comment: @KannE So, how does that relate to the OP's quote?

Comment: @tchrist But the OP should have our sympathies here, because I can't make the phrase quite work in the context of the OP's quote. Can you?

Comment: @KannE Youmisread me. Not *How much?*. How?

Comment: @KannE Well, good for trying to help, but the example itself feels wonky to me!